# Tornado renders html as raw string

Tags: html, tornado

I'm trying to render a static html template in tornado:

```
class HomepageHandler():
    def get(self):
        self.render("homepage.html")
```

However, when I run tornado locally and visit the homepage url, the contents of homepage.html are not rendered. Instead, it looks like the browser treats the contents of homepage.html as a string. This does not happen if I open homepage.html directly using a browser.

Any idea why tornado is serving html as raw strings?

Answer (score 0):

Your `HomepageHandler` needs to inherit `tornado.web.RequestHandler`.

```
import tornado.web

class HomepageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("homepage.html")
```

if you are serving a static file, consider using [StaticFileHandler](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realize that snippet of code was incorrect. However, the problem in my case turned out to be that my static url was incorrect.